# Trying in PHP to mysqldump -v to popen and not getting output

Tags: php, linux, command-line, mysql, popen

I'm writing a wrapper for `mysqldump` and want to show the output nicely in a PHP CLI application.

I'm attempting to run `mysqldump -v` using `popen` so that I can get the verbose output and display progress indicators to the user. However no output is returned (by default it gets logged to the screen via `stdErr`).

I tried adding `2>&1` to the command to push the verbose output from `stdErr` to `stdOut`, but `fread` still doesn't get any output even though the output nolonger goes to the screen via `stdErr`.

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -uroot -proot -v dbname 2>&1 | mysql -uroot -proot dbname2";
$handle = popen($cmd, "r");
$buffer = "";
while ($handle && !feof($handle)){
    $output = fread($handle, 100);
    $buffer .= $output;
    echo sprintf("Buffer: %s\n", $buffer);
}
pclose($handle);
```

Should I use something else instead of `popen`? Or am I simply incorrectly redirecting the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, without having to use a file as a stream buffer.

```
/**
 * PROCESS
 *
 * Process the command
 *
 * @param   int   $buffer  The size of the buffer
 * @param   int   $pipe    The pipe to subscribe to (0=stdIn, 1=stdOut, 2=stdErr)
 *
 * @return  bool  Success or not
 */
public function process($buffer=10, $pipe=1) {
    $handle = proc_open(
        $this->command,
        [
            ["pipe","r"],
            ["pipe","w"],
            ["pipe","w"]
        ],
        $pipes
    );
    if (!is_resource($handle)) {
        return false;
    }

    $output = "";
    $buffer = "";
    $hasLineCallbacks = count($this->onNewLine);
    while ($buffer = fread($pipes[$pipe], 10)) {
        $output .= $buffer;
        if (preg_match("/[\r\n]/", $output)) {
            $segments = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $output);
            while (count($segments) > 1) {
                $line = array_shift($segments);
                if (!$hasLineCallbacks) { continue; }
                foreach ($this->onNewLine as $callback) {
                    if (!$callback["pattern"] || preg_match($callback["pattern"], $line)) {
                        call_user_func($callback["callback"], $line);
                    }
                }
            }
            $output = array_shift($segments);
        }
    }
    proc_close($handle);
    return true;
}
```

I'm basically making `Background` class to run a terminal command and pipe the output to callback functions. It obviously still has a long way to go though.

Thanks for your help, @Victor

Comment: $cmd is `mysqldump -uroot -proot -v dbname | mysql -uroot -proot dbname2`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to actually pipe the mysqldump data into mysql, in which case it might be a bad idea to include error messages into the pipe.

Of course, in this scenario, you cannot capture the mysqldump's output.

You should use the `tee` command:

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot -v dbname | tee /tmp/output | mysql -uroot -proot dbname2
```

This way, you can have the output both in pipe for mysql and `/tmp/output`.
In such a way you can then `fopen` `/tmp/output` for results.

Please note that you might not have the possible errors in the output, as mysql would not be happy seeing them later down the pipe.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it still doesn't seem to work. It just puts the actual output of the `mysqldump` command into the `/tmp/output` file.

Even updating with `tee 2> /tmp/output` didn't work as it's only the standard output from mysqldump that gets piped to tee. I'm still playing around with it though.